# How to filter a ng-repeat by freetext and multiple dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have an object `notification` with the properties

```
EventName
EventDisplayname
SourceName
SourceDisplayname
Message
```

I am using a ng-repeat which uses the notifications retrieved from a webservice and displays them within a simple table.

I have also 3 filters:

- events
- sources
- freetext

This is my HTML code:

```
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">
    <h2>Source-Filter</h2>
    <select id="SourceSelector" style="width: 250px;">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option ng-repeat="source in sources" value="{{source.SourceName}}">{{source.SourceDisplayname}}</option>
    </select>

    <h2>Event-Filter</h2>
    <select id="EventSelector" style="width: 250px;">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option ng-repeat="event in events" value="{{event.EventName}}">{{event.EventDisplayname}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:33%;">
  <h2>Freitext Filter</h2>
  <ul>
      <li><input type="text" style="width:300px" ng-model="search.text" placeholder="Geben Sie ein wonach Sie filtern möchten ..."/></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<tr ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
  <td>{{notification.SourceDisplayName}}</td>
  <td>{{notification.EventDisplayName}}</td>
  <td>{{notification.Message}}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to filter my ng-repeat explicit by the dropwdowns and the freetextbox:

- freetext Textbox should filter only the messages
- dropdown event should only filter the ng-repeats by the lists notification.eventname property
- dropdown source should only filter the ng-repeats by the lists notification.sourcename property

Can i have multiple explicit property filter for a ng-repeat and how could i do this?

Comment: Your freetext filter should filter by notification.message?

Comment: Yes, freetext filter should filter notification.message and dropdown source should filter notification.sourcename and dropdown event -> notification.event

Comment: Is this what you need? See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular
  .module('testApp', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      // fake data
      $scope.notifications = [{
        eventName: 'event2',
        sourceName: 'source1',
        message: 'blah blah blah 3'
      }, {
        eventName: 'event2',
        sourceName: 'source1',
        message: 'blah blah blah 2'
      }, {
        eventName: 'event3',
        sourceName: 'source3',
        message: 'blah blah blah 1'
      }, {
        eventName: 'event3',
        sourceName: 'source2',
        message: 'blah blah blah 3'
      }, {
        eventName: 'event2',
        sourceName: 'source3',
        message: 'blah blah blah 1'
      }];

      $scope.sources = $scope.notifications.map(function(n) {
        return n.sourceName;
      });
      $scope.events = $scope.notifications.map(function(n) {
        return n.eventName;
      });
      $scope.notificationsFiltered = $scope.notifications;

      $scope.$watchGroup(['eventFilter', 'sourceFilter', 'freetextFilter'], function() {
        // apply event filter
        $scope.notificationsFiltered = $scope.notifications;
        if ($scope.eventFilter) {
          $scope.notificationsFiltered = $scope.notificationsFiltered.filter(function(n) {
            return n.eventName == $scope.eventFilter;
          })
        }
        // apply source filter
        if ($scope.sourceFilter) {
          $scope.notificationsFiltered = $scope.notificationsFiltered.filter(function(n) {
            return n.sourceName == $scope.sourceFilter;
          })
        }
        // apply text filter
        if ($scope.freetextFilter) {
          $scope.notificationsFiltered = $scope.notificationsFiltered.filter(function(n) {
            return n.message.indexOf($scope.freetextFilter) > -1;
          })
        }
      });
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <!-- source filter -->
  <select ng-model="sourceFilter">
    <option value="">No filter</option>
    <option ng-repeat="source in sources track by $index" value="{{source}}">{{source}}</option>
  </select>

  <!-- event filter -->
  <select ng-model="eventFilter">
    <option value="">No filter</option>
    <option ng-repeat="event in events track by $index" value="{{event}}">{{event}}</option>
  </select>
  <!-- text filter -->
  <input ng-model="freetextFilter" type="text">

  <!-- filtered results -->
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="notification in notificationsFiltered">
      <td>{{notification.sourceName}}</td>
      <td>{{notification.eventName}}</td>
      <td>{{notification.message}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course there is a better and more clean solution: to use filters. The snippet above is useful if you're planning to use this behavior in just one page and one controller.

Comment: Also please note that I used Angular 1.5.8 in order to use $scope.$watchGroup method.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with: `Of course there is a better and more clean solution: to use filters`

Comment: @STORM I mean custom Angular filters. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11. You can even create a directive or a component. It depends on how you plan to use this results-table on your app.

Comment: But this filters first everything out. I mean i have to select something until it apeears within my table otherwise on page load i have no items.

Comment: Cant i have something like this: `notification in notification | filter:EventName:eventFilter and filter:SourceName:sourceFilter and filter:Message:freetextFilter`? I tried it but is not working

Comment: @STORM you have to create these custom Angular filters before using them.